How can I configure vercel.json to accommodate module imports in both my local dev and deployed remote instances of a flask app?
I have a very basic flask app like this:
- vercel.json
- api/
---- app.py
---- my_module.py

vercel.json looks like this:
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "./api/app.py",
      "use": "@vercel/python",
      "config": {
        "includeFiles": ["api/**"]  
      }
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    { "src": "/(.*)", "dest": "/api/app.py" }
  ]
}

Inside app.py I have import my_module. This works totally fine for my local dev environment. However, it seems that if I want it to work on my vercel hosting, I have to change the imports to something like: from .my_module import some_function with the preceding dot. This now doesn't work on my local instance.
Is there some way that I can configure the vercel.json to just allow me to do normal imports everywhere like import my_module?
